# DNS Record to Redirect Different Ports to Different Hosts

Tags: dns, port, remote-desktop, records, srv

I have a subdomain that I want to use for 2 things at once:

- When accessed through web ports, redirect to *Server 1* to show a web page,
- When that address is used for windows remote desktop, redirect to *Server 2* for remote desktop.

Is it possible to split traffic with DNS record based on the port of incoming request?

I read a bit but I couldn't figure out if SRV records would do the job, or if that would be a backward compatible method.

Thank you to anyone who gives some ideas.

Cheers!

Comment: `SRV` in theory could do that... except that browsers do not use it at all, so you need to have something on port 80 or 443. As for the other point, it depends if the client uses `SRV` records or not (most of them do not). If not, your problem can not be solved just with DNS records.

Answer (score 1):

This is outside of the scope of DNS, as it's role is simply Domain Name Resolution, and *ports* do not exist in the DNS world.

This seems like an idea use-case for something like [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) however, but you will still need one of the servers to route all of the traffic for another unless you use two different host names.

With HAProxy, packet flow would be the following:

User A (Web)

- DNS Lookup of example.com -> 1.1.1.2
- Establish TCP connection to 1.1.1.2 on port 80 (haproxy)
- HAProxy forwards this connection to real webservice on 1.1.1.6

User B (RDP)

- DNS Lookup of example.com -> 1.1.1.2
- Establish TCP connection to 1.1.1.2 on port 5900 (haproxy)
- HAProxy forwards this connection to real RDP service on 1.1.1.7

Comment: Ports do exist in the DNS... see the `SRV` record for example.

Comment: Please do not hijack any IP address to use as examples... And specially not the `1.1.1.1` block!

Comment: So how does an A record know to where port to connect by default?